# wd waitForElementBy... and asserter usage

Tags: javascript, webdriver

I'm using the library provided [here](http://admc.io/wd/) successfully in several tests, but am now stuck trying to use asserters as per their docs as a passed function in the `waitForElementByLinkText` API method.

Here is where I've defined the Asserter:

```
function Asserter(_assert){
  this.assert = _assert;
}

/**
 * asserters.isVisible
 *
 * @asserter
 */
var isDisplayed = new Asserter(
  function(el,cb) {
    el.isDisplayed(function(err, displayed) {
      if(err) { return cb(err); }
      cb(null, displayed);
    });
  }
);

module.exports = {
  Asserter: Asserter,
  isDisplayed: isDisplayed
};
```

Then in my chained script, I am attempting to use it as follows, but the `console.log` executes before the element is visible:

```
.get('http://mydomain.com/mypage')
.elementByLinkText('Reset', function(err, el){
  browser.next('clickElement', el, noop);
})
.waitForElementByLinkText('This is the link text', isDisplayed, 10000, 100, function(err){
  console.log('The page has updated!');
})
```

I believe my code is using a deprecated version of the chaining syntax which is needed to support legacy code coming out of SeBuilder, but makes it hard to follow the samples which all use the new method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to redefine commonly used asserters, please refer to the new example here:

https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/examples/deprecated/wait-for-simple.js

If you need more help, please provide some html/js sample, otherwise it's hard to figure out what you are actually trying to achieve.